# Evidence of a difference in conversion rate between a “ghost” and a “traditional” button?

Tags: buttons, conversion, conversion-rate, trend

Many new sites have been applying the "Ghost Buttons" in landing pages. Same people are saying this is a new trend of 2014.

[image: example A]

[image: example B]

I think with the “ghost button” we have a beautiful and clean design. But it´s not a call to action, that draws user attention and solicits an action.
So it’s important to know when and how we should use it…!

Is there any evidence demonstrating a difference in conversion rate between a “ghost” and a “traditional” button?  In what contexts?

Comment: Hey Pedro, welcome to UX.SE! To me, "what do you think" denotes opinion, not fact. I don't think there is a "correct" answer with the question worded this way.

Comment: `"It's not a call to action, that draws user attention and solicits an action?"`

Why isn't it?

Comment: @rdjs, I think he means that it doesn't catch attention as much as "traditional" buttons (probably meaning high-contrast full-surface buttons).

Comment: I haven't found and tests done on this. To get proper evidence we would need an A/B test with ghost buttons vs a typical cta button.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend looking at this article which talks about a A\B test that was done on seeing the conversion rates while using a solid call to action vs a ghost button in emails. To quote the [article](https://www.elevatedthird.com/article/ghost-buttons-good-bad-spooky-part-2)

> Test A used our baseline newsletter template, which includes ghost
>   buttons. Test B replaced these ghost CTAs with solid blue buttons.
>   Everything else about the two versions was identical.

[image]

### The study results showed that the solid buttons performed better. To quote the [article](https://www.elevatedthird.com/article/ghost-buttons-good-bad-spooky-part-2)

> The overall winner was **Test B**, the version with solid blue
>   buttons. When comparing click rates, the solid button saw a 3.21% rate
>   for clicks per deliveries and a 17.95% rate for clicks per opens.
>
> Test A, in comparison, had a 2.07% rate for clicks per deliveries, and
>   an 11.11% rate for clicks per opens.
>
> **For every email opened, the solid button outperformed the ghost button by nearly 7%!**

Now the key thing to note is that this should not be treated as the gospel truth as ghost buttons do add value to a page with the [proper treatment](http://thinksem.com/blog/ghost-buttons-effective-downright-scary-conversions/) and can serve as effectively as a solid button but its always better A\B testing your variations to see how your users react.

Comment: Updated..I thought I posted the link but i guess i missed it.

Comment: In addition to this information, I'd say a ghost button is mainly useful to show less important CTA's, such as secondary actoins. You often see websites incorporate this, showing 1 solid button, and a ghost button next to it. The ghost button will almost always be the less important CTA.

Comment: Do you also have data from web-usage of a ghost button vs a solid button? I know we've tested it on our websites and it mainly shows that ghost buttons don't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely agree that ghost buttons is the new rising trend in visual design but we need to consider its cons as well while using,

Cons:
Ghost buttons can fall too far into the background and frustrate users. Not all users may be design savvy; some may have trouble identifying an non-traditional button style and knowing how to use it.

Ghost buttons can be tricky to use over images with highly contrasting or varying colors. Typically these buttons are white or black. If you have an image with alternative black and white spaces, a ghost button can be near impossible to see or read.

Ghost buttons rely on size and placement for ease of use. Be cautious when placing the button so that it is easy to find and does not cover a key part of your image.

Ghost buttons can sometimes overpower the image they are paired with.

Ghost button text is more complicated than click here. The words used in these buttons needs to be clearly thought out out, edited and placed in context with the rest of the design.